# How to store SDL_Color in C++ array?

Tags: c++, sdl

```
SDL_Color normColor = {255,255,255};
SDL_Color redColor = {255,0,0};
SDL_Color blackColor = { 0,0,0 };
```

etc.

What kind of array do I need to do something like:

```
typeofarray mycolorArray[95] = {normColor, redColor, blackColor..............};
....
mycolorArray[65] = redColor // to change the color
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SDL_Color sdlColors[] = {normColor, redColor, blackColor..............};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of arrays, you use `enum` instead?

[Color enum](http://haxe.org/ref/enums)

or [Class based example with enum](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/EnumerationTypes.aspx).